# Counting partitions of fixed size in a specific multiset

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition, multisets

If we have the multiset $$\{1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5\},$$ i.e. five distinct elements and five of each type, how many ways can we partition this multiset into five equally sized parts?

I have looked at some previous posts with similar topic, but they were a bit more general. I was thinking that there may be an easier way to deal with the problem in this specific case.

EDIT: I want the partitions to be ”ordered”, so for example the partition 11111|22222|33333|44444|55555 is counted differently from 22222|11111|33333|44444|55555.

EDIT 2: I would ideally want a way of calculating this by hand, and if possible some sort of generalization.

Comment: Are the parts ordered? That is, is $11111\mid 22222\mid 33333\mid 44444\mid 55555$ counted as different from $22222\mid 11111\mid 33333\mid 44444\mid 55555$?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I should’ve been more specific. I want those to be counted as different.

Comment: Then your problem is equivalent to counting the number of $5\times 5$ matrices with nonnegative integer entries whose rows and columns all sum to $5$. It is easy to count this with a computer program. If you are looking for more info than just the numerical answer found by a program (e.g. how to do it by hand, generalizations, etc), then you should probably clarify that by editing

Comment: Yeah I wasn’t really interested in a numerical solution. I’ll edit and keep that in mind for future posts. Thank you.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A110058 discusses the generalization of counting partitions of $\{1^n2^n\cdots n^n\}$ into $n$ distinct parts. Apart from an asymptotic approximation, its seems there is not much known.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link!